# How to send dynamic prices to Paypal?

Tags: html, paypal, payment

I want to get payments with dynamic prices via PayPal HTML buttons. I have different room types and a calendar I'll get the selected room type and the dates and after that I'll send the price to PayPal but I couldn't figure it out how to send the price PayPal without creating prices on PayPal.com.
Thank you.

My button code is here. How I can I send the price to PayPal with this.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="7DZ3M7UQTEHEU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/TW/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Add some code with what you've tried so people can help you build from that

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll edit the message above.@Gjhuizing